# how to separately display products by vendor in shopify liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm having an issue with Shopify products in collection page. I want to display products separately in collection pages. I have one collection `[all products]` and it have more than `200` products. All products have vendor like **Red**, **Green**, **Yellow** and so on. It have more than 10 vendors. If I do manually it work but not expected.

```
{% paginate collection.products by 50 %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% assign vendor = product.vendor | downcase | replace: ' ', '_' %}
        {% if vendor == 'green' %}
            <h2>Green</h2>
            {% include 'product-card' %}
        {% elsif vendor == 'red' %}
            <h2>Red</h2>
            {% include 'product-card' %}
        {% elsif vendor == 'yellow' %}
            <h2>Yellow</h2>
            {% include 'product-card' %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

I don't want to set `if` condition set manually because I don't know how many vendors I have. Vendor `H2` tag showing twice because inside of `forloop`.

How I wanted if vendor is green then show all green vendor products and title shouldn't be twice. Help will be appreciated.

**I want like below example of Image**

[image]

> Note: Unable to showing live example because it's in Shopify also Store password protected.

Comment: Do you want to show all the 200+ products on a single page or do you want to filter product by vendor based on customer selection and use standard Shopify pagination?

Comment: I said I have `200+` products. I don't want to show more than `50` products on page I will add pagination. My issue is I can't filter product by vendor. it shouldn't be customer selection. Example added in question description.

Comment: How are you going to paginate products bearing in mind they are grouped by vendors as per your screen?

Comment: My goal is `50` products per page but product should be separated by vendor. Like above images. Can I show `200+` products without pagination and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can display up to 50 products per vendor (no pagination):

```
{%- for vendor in collection.all_vendors -%}
    <h2>{{ vendor }}</h2>
    {%- assign products = collection.products | where: "vendor", vendor | limit: 1 -%}
    {%- for product in products -%}
        {%- include "product-card" -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I am using the new Shopify theme 2.0 , the provided solution only renders the first products vendors , any suggesting on why not storing the rest of products